# jQuery slick width extending too much

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, slick.js

I've got a simple jQuery slick carousel that I want to use, however when initializing it it always defaults to a width of 7888 for no apparent reason. The HTML is as follows:

```
    <div class="card-slider col-sm-4"
        ng-if="ctrl.slides.length">
            <div ng-repeat="slide in ctrl.slides"
                class="event-card">

                //displaying the information

            </div>
    </div>
```

When initializing it from the console the width just skyrockets and starts messing up the DOM. The code I use is:

```
$('.card-slider').slick({
                accesibility: false,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2500,
                arrows: false,
                infinite: true
            });
```

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried working with multiple carousels already (including [ui.carousel](https://github.com/mihnsen/ui-carousel) that's specific for angular and owl) and they all seem to ignore the parent size and every other style that's been applied to the page up to that point.

Comment: It probably has something to do with css or event the resulting HTML. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Invoking jQuery plugins using class selectors doesn't work well with the AngularJS framework. AngularJS creates and destroys DOM and class selectors don't find yet to be created DOM.